# Preserving state of the checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'n trying to implement some jQuery that will effectively preserve the state of a submitted search form so that the user can see the checkbox selections they made and adjust. The form is submitted as a post action.

Anyone got any suggestions how that can be done?

Regards,

Raj

Comment: If you are using ajax to pass the POST data then the form should retain all values.

Comment: @ Mike Soule :I am not sure,how to do this,Could you please give some sample.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really up to a client side solution if you're performing a standard POST (non-ajax).  You're server side logic would need to feed that information back to your view and your view (which is still being rendered on the server, technically) would drive your checkbox states.

As Mike said, if you post your search using ajax techniques, you won't need to preserve the state because the page never refreshes.  If you're unclear on how to POST a form via Ajax, I suggest hitting google.  Tons of examples available on the interwebs.

Comment: @Gregg:Here i am submitting my form after i got response from ajax.So it will refresh the entire page.

Comment: Ok, so if you are refreshing the entire page, you'll need to preserve form state via your server side logic.  What server side technology are you using?  Java, .NET, PHP, etc?

Comment: @Gregg: I am using java with spring,But here i can bind the form with spring ,because i am poulating checkboxes using html checkboxes.Here i want to preserve state with jquery.

Comment: Hm, I think that's not a good way to go about this.  You should still be able to bind to HTML checkboxes using the JSP expression language. For example...<input type='checkbox' value='${whatever}' checked="${someBooleanValueFromServer}" />

Comment: However, if you still think you want to use jQuery, you'll still need to populate something on your page via the server side code (hidden fields maybe), then use jQuery to grab that data and populate your form accordingly.

Comment: @Gregg:if i select 100 checkboxes,and do the submit.How can i set boolean value to these 100 check boxes.Please explain to me.